# Grails / JSON: recursive data structre for JSON#registerObjectMarshaller

Tags: json, grails, recursion, data-structures, groovy

I have the following self-referencing (recursive) class:

```
class Node {

 String label
 // other attributes go here
 static belongsTo = [parent: Node]
 static hasMany = [children: Node]

 static constraints = {
    label blank: false
    parent nullable: true
    children nullable: true
 }
}
```

I'm using a marshaller in BootStrap.groovy because I only want a few select attributes to be sent to the client, at this stage only the label:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Node) { Node node ->
    return [label: node.label, items: node.children]
}
```

Creating a hierarchy of nodes, such as:

```
def parent1 = new Node(label: "Node 1").save(flush: true)
parent1.addToChildren(new Node(label: "Node 1.1"))

def parent2 = new Node(label: "Node 2").save(flush: true)
def child21 = new Node(label: "Node 2.1")
child21.addToChildren(new Node(label: "Node 2.1.1"))
parent2.addToChildren(child21)
```

and listing them like so:

```
def index(Integer max) {
  params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)

  respond Node.list(params), model: [nodeInstanceCount: Node.count()]
}
```

I would want something like:

```
Node 1
  |
  -- Node 1.1
Node 2
  |
  -- Node 2.1
        |
        -- Node 2.1.1
```

The result looks promising but has a a few nodes too many:

```
Node 1
  |
  -- Node 1.1
Node 2
  |
  -- Node 2.1
        |
        -- Node 2.1.1
Node 1.1
Node 2.1
   |
   -- Node 2.1.1
Node 2.1.1
```

The output is undesired but makes sense: for every node, this method is being called, hence the additional hierarchies / single nodes.

One way I've tried to solve this is by adding a 'processed' property into the Node class. This has the desired effect (every node is only processed once which results in the wanted hierarchy) but introduces the problem of having to manage that state-variable henceforth. Therefore, I want to avoid such hacks.
Another way would be to let the client deal with the received data

Is there an easy way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After having posted the above question, I found the culprit. I hope this will help someone one day in case they're facing a similar issue.

`Node#list` obviously returns *all* nodes when what we want is only the top-level nodes:

```
respond Node.list(params), model: [nodeInstanceCount: Node.count()]
```

To jump straight to the answer, the following solved the issue:

- add a `isRoot` attribute to Node

Then change `index()` to the following:

```
respond Node.findAllByIsRoot(true), model: [nodeInstanceCount: Node.count()]
```

To give some more details:

- the marshaller used to convert this data to the desired JSON format (decided by the `#respond` method through, for example, looking at the `ACCEPT` or `CONTENT-TYPE` header, or like in this case looking at the `format` field in the request URI (as defined in the `UrlMappings#mappings`)) will be of type

  **org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.CollectionMarshaller**

  hence for every object in the list, the marshaller gets called
- the collection marshaller then delegates to the accompanying converter which in our case is of type

  **grails.converters.JSON**
- in its `JSON#value` method, it will eventually call the closure defined in `BootStrap.groovy` class when we registered our marshaller